# How can I make my User.findByIdAndUpdate runs only after the password is set to my new password?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, promise, passport.js

So this is my code, basically what I want to do is changing the password if the user wants to change it, otherwise, it will stay the same. Although, when I changed it does not get hashed because it automatically accepts the input from the frontend (req.body.password). It looks like the last promise does not wait for the previous to complete and get the password set to the new one.

```
 profileRoutes.put("/profile/:userid", (req, res) => {
  const { userid } = req.params;
  const { firstName, lastName, email, imageUrl } = req.body;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let newPassword = null;

  // We need a validation here?
  User.findById(userid)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log("user", user);
      console.log(user.password === password);

      if (user.password !== password) {
        console.log("setting the new pass");
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
        console.log("password:", password, "newPassword:", newPassword);
        password = newPassword;
      }
    }).then(User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userid,
        { firstName, lastName, email, imageUrl, password },
        { new: true }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response after update", response);
          res.status(200).json({ message: `User ${userid} has been updated` });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res
            .status(500)
            .json({ message: "Something went wrong updating the user" });
        })
    );
});
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
    user {
[0]   imageUrl: 'http://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/default-profile-picture-avatar-photo-placeholder-vector-illustration-vector-id1223671392?k=6&m=1223671392&s=612x612&w=0&h=NGxdexflb9EyQchqjQP0m6wYucJBYLfu46KCLNMHZYM=',
[0]   role: 'USER',
[0]   fileUrl: [],
[0]   _id: 60d70093e08f660bebec5589,
[0]   firstName: 'Tiago',
[0]   lastName: 'Pereira',
[0]   email: 'tiago@gmail.com',
[0]   password: '$2a$10$yExMB9eSs1EyqSbrvE8a1udqOMo09GG.SSyr0BJmZb70mqpcJByiC',
[0]   createdAt: 2021-06-26T10:25:23.245Z,
[0]   updatedAt: 2021-06-26T10:25:23.245Z,
[0]   __v: 0
[0] }
[0] false
[0] setting the new pass
[0] password: qwertyasd newPassword: $2a$10$Xudvsq4CkkDU7bHcQIvH.OyfhlDe1/u3Q1Qv6wmv79f4B5TSFVDi.
[0] response after update {
[0]   imageUrl: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dulzxixhi/image/upload/v1624703139/School%27s%20Cool/wnc8vjpgunrkvolnldb4.jpg',
[0]   role: 'USER',
[0]   fileUrl: [],
[0]   _id: 60d70093e08f660bebec5589,
[0]   firstName: 'Tiago',
[0]   lastName: 'Pereira',
[0]   email: 'tiago@gmail.com',
[0]   password: 'qwertyasd',
[0]   createdAt: 2021-06-26T10:25:23.245Z,
[0]   updatedAt: 2021-06-26T10:26:20.237Z,
[0]   __v: 0
[0] }
```

Comment: But it is inside a promise, so it should set the password to the new password, and then the findByIdAndUpdate should start, right?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actualy simple. We have to return what we want to pass throw:

```
        User.findById(userid)
        .then((user) => {
          if (user.password !== password) {
            const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    
            password = newPassword;
          }
          return password;
// I am returning the password to be able to pass it to the next then() and 
// use it as follows
        })
        .then((password) => {
          User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            userid,
            {
              firstName,
              lastName,
              email,
              imageUrl,
              password,
              newChannelEmailNotification,
              newEventEmailNotification,
              newPostEmailNotification,
            },
            { new: true }
          )
            .then((response) => {
              console.log("response after update", response);
              res.status(200).json({ message: `User ${userid} has been updated` });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              res
                .status(500)
                .json({ message: "Something went wrong updating the user" });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't directly compare a hashed password with a normal string.

`console.log(user.password === password); //this will always prints false`

You have to use `bcrypt.compareSync`. It takes two inputs (normal string, hash) and returns a boolean (true if matches).

And you're using the synchronous approach in Bcrypt, so it won't return a promise. This means you can't use `.then()`.

**Solution with minimum changes to the existing code**:

Just use `findByIdAndUpdate` inside the if block.

```
const isMatching = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

if (isMatching) {
        console.log("setting the new pass");
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
        console.log("password:", password, "newPassword:", newPassword);
        password = newPassword;

   User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userid,
        { firstName, lastName, email, imageUrl, password },
        { new: true }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response after update", response);
          res.status(200).json({ message: `User ${userid} has been updated` });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res
            .status(500)
            .json({ message: "Something went wrong updating the user" });
        })
}
```

Comment: Hi @TiagoPereira, I was rushing through and missed the part that you haven't use `bcrypt.cmpareSync` to compare the two passwords. I have updated my answer now. Can you give a try and tell me what happens?